# Not able to update database values in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

We are trying to design a smart parking system using raspberry Pi in Python.

We created a database which has 4 fields namely Slot1 slot 2 slot3 Slot4

This are the parking slots which we are testing if it is empty or occupied usint IR sensors.

We completely designed and working code using python and was able to implement the sensors thingy and its working fine.

But the only issue we are facing is its not updating values 0 or 1 in database (1 is occupied).

We have 8 IR sensors (2 for each slot)

Only problem is database is not getting updated with 1 if slot is occupied.

Here is our code.

```
   #!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO           # import RPi.GPIO module

from time import sleep          #for 2 second delay

#import MySQLdb

import mysql.connector as mariadb


mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='raspberry', database='m2')

cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(buffered=True)



GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)            # choose BCM or BOARD


GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(29, GPIO.OUT) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(31, GPIO.OUT) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(33, GPIO.OUT) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(35, GPIO.OUT) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.IN) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.IN) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.IN) # set a port/pin as an output

GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN) # set a port/pin as an output


while(True):

                a=GPIO.input(12)

                b=GPIO.input(16)

                c=GPIO.input(18)

                d=GPIO.input(22)

                e=GPIO.input(32)

                f=GPIO.input(36)

                g=GPIO.input(38)

                h=GPIO.input(40)

                print h

                left=0

                right=0

                if(a == e and a == 0):

                        sleep(2)

                        if(a == e and a == 0):

                                GPIO.output(7,0)

                                left=left+1

                                aa=1

                                cursor.execute("UPDATE slots SET slot1='1' WHERE id='1'")

                                mariadb_connection.commit()

                        #       print a

                        #       print e

                elif((a == e and a == 1) or (a != e)):

                        GPIO.output(7,1)

                        left=left-1

                        aa=0

                        cursor.execute("UPDATE slots SET slot1='0' WHERE id='1'")

                        mariadb_connection.commit()

                        #print a

                                   #       print e

                elif((a == e and a == 1) or (a != e)):

                        GPIO.output(7,1)

                        left=left-1

                        aa=0

                        cursor.execute("UPDATE slots SET slot1='0' WHERE id='1'")

                        mariadb_connection.commit()

                        #print a

                        #print e

                if(b == f and b == 0):

                        sleep(2)

                        if(b == f and b == 0):

                                GPIO.output(11,0)

                                left=left+1

                                bb=1

                                cursor.execute("UPDATE slots SET slot2='1' WHERE id='1'")

                                mariadb_connection.commit()

                        #       print b

                        #       print f

                elif((b == f and b == 1) or (b != f)):

                        GPIO.output(11,1)

                        left=left-1

                        bb=0

                        cursor.execute("UPDATE slots SET slot2='0' WHERE id='1'")

                        mariadb_connection.commit()

                        #print b

                        #print f

                if(c == g and c == 0):

                                        sleep(2)

                        if(c == g and c == 0):

                                GPIO.output(13,0)

                                right=right+1

                                cc=1

                                cursor.execute("UPDATE `slots` SET `slot3`=1 WHERE `id`=1")

                                mariadb_connection.commit()

                        #       print c

                        #       print g

                elif((c == g and c == 1) or (c != g)):

                        GPIO.output(13,1)

                        right=right-1

                        cc=0

                        cursor.execute("UPDATE slots SET slot3='0' WHERE id='1'")

                        mariadb_connection.commit()

                        #print c

                        #print g

                if(d == h and d == 0):

                        sleep(2)

                        if(d == h and d == 0):

 sleep(2)

                        if(d == h and d == 0):

                                GPIO.output(15,0)

                                right=right+1

                                dd=1

                                cursor.execute("UPDATE slots SET slot4='1' WHERE id='1'")

                                mariadb_connection.commit()

                        #       print d

                        #       print h

                elif((d == h and d == 0) or (d != h)):

                        GPIO.output(15,1)

                        right=right-1

                        dd=0

                        cursor.execute("UPDATE slots SET slot4='0' WHERE id='1'")

                        mariadb_connection.commit()

                        #print d

                        #print h

                """if((a == e and a == 0) or (a != e)):

                        GPIO.output(7,1)

                        left=left-1

                        print a

                        print e"""

 """ if((b == f and b == 0) or (b != f)):

                        GPIO.output(11,1)

                        left=left-1

                        print b

                        print f"""

                """if((c == g and c == 0) or (c != g)):

                        GPIO.output(13,1)

                        right=right-1

                        print c

                        print g"""

                """if((d == h and d == 0) or (d != h)):

                        GPIO.output(15,1)

                        right=right-1

                        print d

                        print h"""

                if((left < right and left < 2) or (left < 0)):

                                GPIO.output(29,1)

                                GPIO.output(31,1)

                                GPIO.output(33,0)

                                GPIO.output(35,0)  elif(left > right and right < 2):

                                GPIO.output(29,1)

                                GPIO.output(33,1)

                                GPIO.output(31,0)

                                GPIO.output(35,0)

                elif(left == right and left == 2):

                                GPIO.output(35,1)

                                GPIO.output(29,0)

                                GPIO.output(33,0)

                                GPIO.output(31,0)

                else:

                                GPIO.output(29,1)

                                GPIO.output(31,1)

                                GPIO.output(33,0)

                                GPIO.output(35,0)

                if(aa == 1):

                        aa=0

                if(bb == 1):

                        bb=0

                if(cc == 1):

                cc=0

                   if(dd == 1):

                        dd=0


                print left

                print right

                cursor.execute("SELECT slot1,slot2,slot3,slot4 FROM slots WHERE id='1'")

                mariadb_connection.commit()

cursor.close()

mariadb_connection.close()
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Please make an effort to remove the parts of your code that aren't relevant to your problem (but be sure what you leave is still sufficient to fully reproduce it). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Let me guess;  after the first write to the database, nothing else gets written to the DB?

Comment: It looks like you are using mysql for the database.  What engine is your table using (myisam, or innodb)? how about autocommit?